# Why does music resonate with everyone?

Tags: cognitive-psychology

Why do humans have a predisposition to finding meaning in listening to music? One would imagine this not to be the case since we evolved as visual animals with a natural inclination to reading facial expressions to deduce emotions. Music appears to be very dense, compared to other art forms, it is able to succinctly, vividly, and accurately summarise experiences.

This could be answered using phenomenology - humans have to perceive the world through a lens of subjectivity. We, therefore, evolve to regard meaning as an instinct. Music compliments meaning since a compelling musical art is composed of layers all working harmoniously. Meaning is found in the appreciation of layered order.

Comment: The underpinning of enjoyment of music appears go back far into our common ancestry with other animals. It's unclear how an answer can be given as the question is now framed, and as we require questioners to show their prior research attempts to find an answer. I'd take a look at [Steven Pinker's view](https://whyevolutionistrue.com/2014/08/14/steve-pinker-on-the-evolutionary-significance-of-music/) which has merit, but in my view isn't the whole picture, and [Zoomusicology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zoomusicology) for further reading. [Also](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Music_psychology)

Comment: Similar to [Satisfaction from music due to correct prediction of a sound](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/q/25286/7001).  See [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evolutionary_musicology) for a review of some of the most common hypotheses on why we like music.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Satisfaction from music due to correct prediction of a sound](https://psychology.stackexchange.com/questions/25286/satisfaction-from-music-due-to-correct-prediction-of-a-sound)